# storeAs function store file with random name in /tmp/ Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, file, file-upload

I've got a form for my register, I'm asking to my RegisterController to store the file pass with my form to a specific folder and a specific name.

My problem is that my file is upload but in a folder named /tmp and with a random name.
Here is my code :

```
$request = request();

    // GET THE CURRENT REQUEST AND SET A NAME FOR THE STORAGE
    $profileImage = $request->file('license');
    $profileImageSaveAsName = $profileImage.'_.'.$profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // STORE THE FILE TO THE PUBLIC FOLDER WITH THE NAME
    $success = $profileImage->storeAs('public/licenses', $profileImageSaveAsName);
```

Before I've got a Validator from laravel and after I've got the db insertion.
Why with the storeAs function, it upload my file in /tmp and with a random name ?
P.S : I use the Laravel's auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the /tmp/tmpname.tmp is the default of php.
`storeAs()` method allow to save the file in a directory under `/storage/` not in `/public/`
eg. `storeAs('public/licenses')` will try to save in `/storage/public/licenses`
do you have that directory ? or maybe you meant `storeAs('app/public/licenses')` ?

Comment: I've created a link with artisan make:link public/storage. So if that's the problem I'll check this out. I thought that it'll check in public so :). Thanks mate